# How To Implement Flutter app thats read real time sensor value using Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

This  my code but this some error with snapsot map

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Dashboard extends StatefulWidget {
  const Dashboard({super.key});

  @override
  State<Dashboard> createState() => _DashboardState();
}

class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {
  
  Future<void> readSensorValues() async {
    final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot =
        (await FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('sensor').once()) as DataSnapshot;
    final Map<String, dynamic> data =
        Map<String, dynamic>.from(dataSnapshot.value);

    final double sensorEC = (data['EC'] as int).toDouble();
    final double sensorPH = (data['PH'] as int).toDouble();
    final double sensorRTD = (data['RTD'] as int).toDouble();
    final double humidity = (data['humidity']as int).toDouble();
    final double temperature = (data['temperature'] as int).toDouble();

    print('Sensor EC is $sensorEC');
    print('Sensor PH $sensorPH');
    print('Sensor RTD $sensorRTD'); 
    print('Sensor humidity $humidity');  
    print('Sensor temperature $temperature');
  }
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want some function to read the value of Data Sensor EC, PH, RTD, humidity, Temperature then convert it into a float value on the flutter app.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've provided is mostly correct, but it seems you're having an issue with casting the snapshot value to DataSnapshot. Firebase's once() method should already return a DataSnapshot, so the explicit casting as DataSnapshot is not necessary.

Here's a slightly modified version of your readSensorValues method:

```
Future<void> readSensorValues() async {
  DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('sensor');
  DataSnapshot dataSnapshot = await ref.once();
  
  if(dataSnapshot.value != null) {
    Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>.from(dataSnapshot.value);

    double sensorEC = (data['EC'] as num).toDouble();
    double sensorPH = (data['PH'] as num).toDouble();
    double sensorRTD = (data['RTD'] as num).toDouble();
    double humidity = (data['humidity'] as num).toDouble();
    double temperature = (data['temperature'] as num).toDouble();

    print('Sensor EC is $sensorEC');
    print('Sensor PH $sensorPH');
    print('Sensor RTD $sensorRTD'); 
    print('Sensor humidity $humidity');  
    print('Sensor temperature $temperature');
  } else {
    print('No data found in Firebase');
  }
}
```

Some changes and points to note:

Removed the unnecessary casting as DataSnapshot.
Used num type instead of int because Firebase might return either int or double for numeric values, and then we explicitly convert to double.
Added a null check for the dataSnapshot.value to ensure that the app doesn't crash if there's no data in Firebase.
Now, you can call the readSensorValues() function in your build method or anywhere else to read the sensor values from Firebase.

Comment: Just same Bro agot some errorThe argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'.dartargument_type_not_assignable
data_snapshot.dart(24, 15): 'value' refers to a property so it couldn't be promoted. See http://dart.dev/go/non-promo-property
DataSnapshot dataSnapshot

Comment: And this A value of type 'DatabaseEvent' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'DataSnapshot'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'DataSnapshot'.dartinvalid_assignment